# Almacenar respuesta de terminal en Variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

Subo videos mediante API a un servidor de streaming con este código:

```
import requests
import os
import time

url = ("https://api.highload.to/file/ul?login=49e3d32723606b2d&key=b4b006363267p3z")
data = requests.get(url)

api= (data.text[78:-39])

video=('test.mp4"')

time.sleep(20)

comando = (('curl -k -F "file=@F:/videos/') + str(video) + (' -F login=49e3d32723606b2d -F key=b4b006363267p3z  ') +  str(api))




os.system (comando)
```

Funciona perfectamente (el login y key que he indicado en el ejemplo no son los reales ) me gustaría almacenar la respuesta que recibo en el terminal cuando ya se subió el video para poder comprobar y pasar al siguiente mediante un for.

en el terminal recibo esto y es lo que quiero guardar en una variable:

```
{"msg":"OK","status":200,"result":{"id":"fvcbvgcp2wdx","status":200,"name":"test.mp4","size":333417625,"folder":null,"content_type":"application/octet-stream"}}
```

Comment: Hola. Puedes incluir en el comando la asignación de una variable de entorno o puedes escribir el resultado en un archivo para leerlo al terminar la ejecución. Un detalle que tal vez quieras tomar en cuenta es el de ocultar tus credenciales de acceso al publicar preguntas, y de hecho también podrías considerar el tomar esos datos de variables de entorno o archivos .env

Comment: gracias Eduardo pero es justo lo que no se hacer, tendrías algún código de ejemplo?

Comment: los credenciales no son reales :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

creo que para estas ocasiones es recomendable utilizar el módulo `subprocess` el cual nos permite ejecutar comandos y poder manejar la salida de datos, por ende también guardarlos.

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

res = Popen(comando, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
stdout, err = res.communicate()  
print(stdout)
```

Con esto ya estarías guardando el resultado del comando en la variable `stdout`. Por cierto también puedes usar *f-string* para que sea más entendible la forma en que *armas* el comando :D.

Comment: Mañana lo probaré y te comento! mil gracias

Comment: muy bien, estaré atento cualquier cosa :D.

Comment: es justo lo que decia Christian, ya luego en la variable busco lo que necesito y listo, gracias